# Simulate a DirectShow Webcam

Tags: .net, directx, directshow, directshow.net

I am a developer in DotNet. I want to give skype a possibility to add a webcam simulator and send my bitmap frames to the DirectShow simulator. In this case I can draw my images in my application and on skype I can share this images to my friend.

[image: Photo][image: Webcam][image: DirectX]

I was on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407344%28VS.85%29.aspx
but it's no Dotnet and I am not sure what example I should believe in.

I also saw:
http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/
But as far as I undestand, here I cannot do with this framework what I need, or can I?

My question is: What is basically needed to create such an DirectShow item?

Regards

Comment: As much as I like C# and dotnet, doing this in dotnet instead of C++ is like inserting a screw using a hammer instead of a screwdriver...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible through a virtual device, see

- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)
- [Is it possible to fake a video stream as virtual cam that is visible in Skype, Lync etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252225/is-it-possible-to-fake-a-video-stream-as-virtual-cam-that-is-visible-in-skype-l)

You will have hard time implementing this in C# only, as the APIs are for native code.

Comment: Can you please answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469747/use-directshow-for-streaming-on-server-app

Answer (score 1):

The best example code for this is going to OBS and [OBS Virtualcam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/). OBS is coded with Qt with a Chromium and FFMPEG backend.  I highly recommend that you clone the [OBS git repo](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio).

`git clone https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git`