# Create fake webcam with ffmpeg on Windows?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg has all kinds of options in it to record video off of a webcam, transcode video, send video up to streaming servers. Is there a way to loop over a file and make it look like a webcam?

I found this for Linux:
https://gist.github.com/zburgermeiszter/42b651a11f17578d9787

I've search around a lot to try to find something for Windows, but have not yet found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not part of FFmpeg so you'll need to create this "virtual video device" yourself. See e.g. [How to create virtual webcam in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693131/how-to-create-virtual-webcam-in-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks Mike. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So after you create the virtual webcam in Windows, can you use ffmpeg to stream video to it as input?

Comment: Depends on how you design your virtual camera. You can make it act as a bridge so to ffmpeg it looks like an output device. The one I'm using I approach by COM.